# Condition for Projective Variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, maximal-and-prime-ideals, groebner-basis, multivariate-polynomial

The definition of projective variety is equivalent to the locus of zero set of homogeneous polynomials that generate a prime ideal in the algebraically closed field they are a subset of (polynomial ring).

Now, what about the variety generated by the locus of zero set of homogeneous polynomials that do not necessarily generate a prime ideal, but are a groebner basis for the ideal they generate? Are these varieties specially studied? Can these be decomposed to projective varieties?
Thanks beforehand.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "that generate a prime ideal in the algebraically closed field they are a subset of". Do you mean in the polynomial ring?

Comment: @user45878 yes, the polynomial ring